# build Flutter client for IPFS

Tags: flutter, ipfs

please trying to build a FLUTTER client to access IPFS server using **dart_ipfs_client**
my function

```
sendMessage() async {
    print('-------------1');
    var ipfs = Ipfs(url: 'http://10.0.2.2:5001');
    print('-------------2');
    var addRes = await ipfs.add(utf8.encode('Hello World!'));
    print('-------------3');
  }
```

I have this error

> [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception:
> SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address
> = 10.0.2.2, port = 41004
> Please is the any solution to fix this?

Comment: Hello @donvex, did you find a solution to your issue ?